# Why is my airbrush function not working in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am creating a basic paint app and I want to create an airbrush function, and have other functions for different styles of brushes. Basically, the user clicks an icon to select the style of brush, and then when they click and hold over the canvas, the respective brush will paint on the canvas. Here is my code:
The main loop:

```
def paintScreen():
    intro = True
    gameDisplay.fill(cyan)
    message_to_screen('Welcome to PyPaint', black, -300, 'large')
    cur = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, white, (50, 120, displayWidth - 100, displayHeight - 240))

        button('X', 20, 20, 50, 50, red, lightRed, action = 'quit')
        icon(airbrushIcon, white, 50, displayHeight - 101, 51, 51, white, grey, 'airbrush')
        icon(pencilIcon, white, 140, displayHeight - 101, 51, 51, white, grey, 'pencil')
        icon(calligraphyIcon, white, 230, displayHeight - 101, 51, 51, white, grey, 'calligraphy')
        pygame.display.update()
        if cur[0] > 50 < displayWidth - 50 and cur [1] > 120 < displayHeight - 120:
            if airbrush == True:
                airbrush()
```

the icon function:

```
def icon(icon, colour, x, y, width, height, inactiveColour, activeColour, action = None):
    cur = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if x + width > cur[0] > x and y + height > cur[1] > y:#if the cursor is over the button
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, activeColour, (x, y, width, height))
        gameDisplay.blit(icon, (x, y))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            if action == 'quit':
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            elif action == 'pencil':
                pencil = True
                return pencil
            elif action == 'airbrush':
                airbrush = True
                return airbrush
            elif action == 'calligraphy':
                calligraphy = True
                return calligraphy
            elif action == 'erase':
                eraser = True
                return eraser
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, inactiveColour, (x, y, width, height))
        gameDisplay.blit(icon, (x, y))
```

the airbrush function:

```
def airbrush(brushSize = 3):
    airbrush = True
    cur = pygame.mouse.get_pos() #cur[0] is x location, cur[1] is y location
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    while airbrush == True:
        if click[0] == True:
            if cur[0] > 50 < displayWidth - 50 and cur[1] > 120 < displayHeight - 120: #if the cursor is above the canvas
                #the area of the canvas is x(50, width-50) y(120, width-120)
                pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay, black, (cur[0] + random.randrange(brushSize), cur[1] + random.randrange(brushSize)), random.randrange(1, 5))
                pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(60)
```

What can I do to make the airbrush function work? When running the app, it doesn't return any errors, it just doesn't work at all

Comment: Are you confident the `airbrush()` function is getting called properly?  Maybe a few `print()` statements would help identify any errors in logic flow.

Comment: I am sure it is being called. I even moved the statement that draws the canvas outside the while loop so it doesn't draw over the ink from the airbrush function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several flaws:

- You mix up the business logic and the drawing, which clutters up your code. We'll fix it later
- In your `icon` function, you're setting local variables (like `airbrush` and `pencil` etc), which does not affect global variables with the same name. Also you return their value after setting them and never use that value.
- If your `airbrush` function would be called, you could never leave that function, because there's no way to set `airbrush` to false
- The function would also not work because you don't handle events in its loop, which would result in your window no longer responding once the event queue fills up

You should make use of polymorphism, something like this:

```
import pygame
import pygame.freetype
import random

def bresenham_line(start, end):
    x1, y1 = start
    x2, y2 = end
    dx = x2 - x1
    dy = y2 - y1
    is_steep = abs(dy) > abs(dx)
    if is_steep:
        x1, y1 = y1, x1
        x2, y2 = y2, x2
    swapped = False
    if x1 > x2:
        x1, x2 = x2, x1
        y1, y2 = y2, y1
        swapped = True
    dx = x2 - x1
    dy = y2 - y1
    error = int(dx / 2.0)
    ystep = 1 if y1 < y2 else -1
    y = y1
    points = []
    for x in range(x1, x2 + 1):
        coord = (y, x) if is_steep else (x, y)
        points.append(coord)
        error -= abs(dy)
        if error < 0:
            y += ystep
            error += dx
    if swapped:
        points.reverse()
    return points

class Brush(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, font, canvas, tmpcanvas, icon, brushes, offset):
        super().__init__(brushes)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((32, 32))
        self.image.fill(pygame.Color('grey'))
        font.render_to(self.image, (8, 7), icon)
        self.other_image = self.image.copy()
        pygame.draw.rect(self.other_image, pygame.Color('red'), self.other_image.get_rect(), 3)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)
        self.active = False
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.tmpcanvas = tmpcanvas
        self.brushes = brushes
        self.offset = offset
        self.mouse_pos = None

    def translate(self, pos):
        return pos[0] - self.offset[0], pos[1] - self.offset[1]

    def draw_to_canvas(self):
        pass

    def flip(self):
        self.active = not self.active
        self.image, self.other_image = self.other_image, self.image        

    def update(self, events):
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and self.rect.collidepoint(e.pos):
                for brush in self.brushes:
                    if brush.active:
                        brush.flip()
                self.flip()

        self.mouse_pos = self.translate(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
        if self.active:
            self.draw_to_canvas()

class Pencil(Brush):
    def __init__(self, pos, font, canvas, tmpcanvas, brushes, offset):
        super().__init__(pos, font, canvas, tmpcanvas, 'P', brushes, offset)
        self.prev_pos = None

    def draw_to_canvas(self):
        pressed = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        if pressed[0] and self.prev_pos:
            pygame.draw.line(self.canvas, pygame.Color('red'), self.prev_pos, self.mouse_pos)
        self.prev_pos = self.mouse_pos

class Calligraphy(Brush):
    def __init__(self, pos, font, canvas, tmpcanvas, brushes, offset):
        super().__init__(pos, font, canvas, tmpcanvas, 'C', brushes, offset)
        self.prev_pos = None

    def draw_to_canvas(self):
        pressed = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        if pressed[0] and self.prev_pos:
            for x, y in bresenham_line(self.prev_pos, self.mouse_pos):
                pygame.draw.rect(self.canvas, pygame.Color('orange'), (x, y, 5, 15))
        self.prev_pos = self.mouse_pos 

class Airbrush(Brush):
    def __init__(self, pos, font, canvas, tmpcanvas, brushes, offset):
        super().__init__(pos, font, canvas, tmpcanvas, 'A', brushes, offset)

    def draw_to_canvas(self):
        pressed = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        if pressed[0]:
            pygame.draw.circle(self.canvas, pygame.Color('green'), 
            (self.mouse_pos[0] + random.randrange(-13, 13), self.mouse_pos[1] + random.randrange(-13, 13)), 
            random.randrange(1, 5))

class LineTool(Brush):
    def __init__(self, pos, font, canvas, tmpcanvas, brushes, offset):
        super().__init__(pos, font, canvas, tmpcanvas, 'L', brushes, offset)
        self.start = None

    def draw_to_canvas(self):
        pressed = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        if pressed[0]:
            if not self.start:
                self.start = self.mouse_pos
            pygame.draw.line(self.tmpcanvas, pygame.Color('yellow'), self.start, self.mouse_pos)
        else:
            if self.start:
                pygame.draw.line(self.canvas, pygame.Color('yellow'), self.start, self.mouse_pos)
                self.start = None

class Clear(Brush):
    def __init__(self, pos, font, canvas, tmpcanvas, brushes, offset):
        super().__init__(pos, font, canvas, tmpcanvas, '*', brushes, offset)

    def draw_to_canvas(self):
        pressed = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        if pressed[0]:
            self.canvas.fill((1, 1, 1))
            self.flip()

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
    sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    font = pygame.freetype.SysFont(None, 26)
    offset = 0, 50
    canvas = pygame.Surface((500, 450))
    canvas.set_colorkey((1,1,1))
    canvas.fill((1,1,1))
    tmpcanvas = canvas.copy()

    x=10
    for tool in (Pencil, Calligraphy, Airbrush, LineTool, Clear):
        tool((x, 10), font, canvas, tmpcanvas, sprites, offset)
        x+= 40

    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
        tmpcanvas.fill((1, 1, 1))
        sprites.update(events)
        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        screen.blit(canvas, offset)
        screen.blit(tmpcanvas, offset)
        sprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

In this example, we have a `Brush` base class that handles drawing of the icon and keeping track of the `active`-state of the brush, and the subclasses handle the actual drawing.

This way, we can easily add new brushes/tools quite easily by creating a new class and implementing the `draw_to_canvas` function.

Comment: So my code currently is supposed to run like this:
In the while loop, it paints all the buttons and etc, then it checks if the cursor is on the canvas, then it checks if airbrush is set to true. If airbrush is set to true, it checks if the mouse is down. If the mouse is down, it should paint. This is all in the single while loop. I did change it so that the airbrush() function no longer creates a while loop, instead it draws something, and that can be repeated in the initial while loop. What exactly are the flaws with this method?

Comment: As I said in my answer, the main flaws are: you're mixing up local and global variables, so by setting `airbrush` to `True` in the `icon` function (a local variable) you're not changing the `airbrush` variable (which, by the way, points to a function) you check for in the `paintScreen` function, and you create a second loop that you can't leave in the `airbrush` function.

Comment: But I did remove the while loop from the airbrush function, so that now the function just draws and updates the display. I also changed my code so that the airbrush variable was global. Would the variable having the same name as a function cause any issues?

Comment: @NormyHaddad Yes; if you create a function `foo` and then set `foo = True` your function is gone because `foo` now points to `True` instead.